# How to insert dynamic value into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, dynamic

i have a form which content name,phone no ,address,personal info....etc

and i had given an option to user which fields he want to insert using a checkbox

the field which is has checked apper on  other  page eg: if he has seleted name and address

...then name and address appers....so how can i make my mysql database.....so if someone select all option in my form ....my mysql table should save all data...

so basically my question is how can i make my mysql database dynamically...so if user selets 2 option it can insert 2 values  & if user select all option he can save all the values.....

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have be clear is their any mandatory field in all your fields and i think it must be some mandatory otherwise what will happen is if user will just submit form it will insert blank row into database so be clear which field you want to make mandatory.

Then put all others in checkbox and make a database table with all the fields name with default value null.

and use a array to insert data into database each time in this way you dont have to write every time the fields name and their value

```
< form >
     < input type="text" name="detail['name']" value="" / >
     < input type="text" name="detail['age']" value="" / >
     < input type="text" name="detail['email']" value="" / >
     .
     .
     .
     .
   < / form >
```

what will you get on another end

```
 $detail = $_POST['detail'];
```

now all the values posted from form with their fields name are inside $detail.

No its your turn to make a query which will take key of $detail array as columns of table and value of $detail is value to be inserted in db like

```
 $field_string = '';
 $value_string = '';

 foreach($detail as $key => $val){

   $field_string = $key.",";
   $value_string = $value.",";       

 }
 $field_string = trim($field_string, ",");
 $value_string = trim($value_string, ",");

$query = "INSERT INTO table ($field_string) VALUES ($value_string) ";
```

That's all i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Create table with all the fields in database.selected option field value will be inserted and for other fields null will be inserted

Answer (score 0):

what all you can do is either **create a database with all the columns** in the tables or just **add a column again and again** in the table `if it does not exist` but a column that has been added into the database will exist even though you do not add data in it until you delete it

Answer (score 0):

first get all column number with following select statement
(during the example i assume you have a class (as always i have) to read the data from DB)

```
select count(*) from cols where table_name='MyTableName'
```

if the number of row was same as answer of above query so you have to show

```
select * from MyTableName
```

if not :

i assume you save the data in $UserSelectedField

```
$userSelectedField=implode($UserSelectedField,',');
$sql="select $UserSelectedField from MyTableName ";
```

then you can show the answer of $sql